Is there any actual difference between these 2 definitions of a state value function?
The definition of the value function in TRPO paper is
\begin{align}
V_\pi(s_t) &= \mathbb{E}_{a_t,s_{t+1},\ldots} \left[ \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \gamma^l r(s_{t+l}) \right], \\[10pt]
a_t &\sim \pi(a_t|s_t), \quad s_{t+1} \sim P(s_{t+1}|s_t, a_t) \text{ for } t \geq 0.
\end{align}
In this book the value function is defined as
\begin{equation}
V_M^\pi(s) = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t r(s_t, a_t) \;\middle|\; \pi, s_0 = s\right],
\end{equation}
Is there any difference between those definitions or are they equivalent? It seems the first one takes into account that the trajectory is begining somewhere else and passing through state $s_t$y? The second defintion take into account just trajectories that start in the desire state to compute the expectation, but that means that trajectories that pass through the state don't matter for the value function?
Can anyone help me understand this?

The notation varies a lot, because there is no such rule on how to write it formally.
The definition of the value is just the "expected sum of (discounted) reward from a state given a policy", therefore the second one, in my opinion, is way clearer than the first one
Yet, the first one is also not entirely wrong, but both miss the fact that the reward function is a function of the state, action and also possibly the new state, so $r(s,a,s')$

Both definitions are equivalent. The point of Markov decision processes is that only the previous state has an impact on the transition dynamics, not the entire history. You could replace the $t$ in the first expression by a $0$ without running into any issues. This, in turn, would be equivalent to writing $$V_\pi(s) = \mathbb E_{a_0,s_1,\dots}\left[\sum_{l=0}^\infty \gamma^l r(s_l)\mid s_0 = s\right],$$ where $a_t \sim \pi(a_t \mid s_t)$ and $s_{t+1} \sim P(s_{t+1} \mid s_t, a_t)$ for $t \geq 0$, which starts to resemble the second definition. How to express that the policy $\pi$ influences the transition dynamics wildly differs in the literature. Some use $\mathbb E_\pi[\dots]$, others use $\mathbb E[\dots \mid \pi]$, like the second one.
The only remaining difference are the arguments to $r$. As Alberto pointed out, the most common form is $r(s, a, s')$, but the others are not wrong. They are in fact all equivalent and people use different definitions based on what they aim to do with it. Modeling is easier with $r(s,a,s')$ since it's the most versatile, but for theory, one might prefer $r(s)$ since it is just a function defined on the vertices of a directed graph.

To go from $r(s)$ to $r(s,a)$, simply define $r(s,a) = r(s)$ for all $a \in A$. The same can be done for $r(s,a,s')$.
To go from $r(s,a,s')$ to $r(s,a)$, set $r(s,a) = \mathbb E_{s'}[r(s,a,s')]$.
To go from $r(s,a)$ to $r(s)$, we can extend the state space of the MDP to $S \cup (S \times A)$. For instance, let's say I have some MDP with $S = \{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$ and $A = \{a_1, a_2\}$. If I execute action $a_1$ in $s_1$ in the original MDP, I might go to $s_2$ with $0.5$ probability, and to $s_3$ with $0.5$ probability. In the new MDP, I will go to $(s_1,a_1)$ with probability $1$, obtain my reward $r((s_1,a_1))$ (which now comes from the reward function of the original MDP, namely $r(s_1,a_1)$), and then - regardless of which action I execute next - go to state $s_2$ or $s_3$ with probabilities $0.5$ each. We also set $r(s) = 0$ for any $s \in S$.

While the reward of a single trajectory might change with the above transformations, the expected reward of any policy should stay the same. What I laid out is not very formal, but I hope it gets the idea across.
